# Crash: While updating UIImageView using SDWebImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, sdwebimage

What I want to implement is, when a user click on any CollectionViewCell then a new view will be displayed for **zooming** and **scrolling**. Basically I have two different class named MyCollectionViewController and MyScrollViewController. I have following code portion in my collection view controller:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let VC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myScrollVC") as? MyScrollViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC!, animated: true)
    VC?.setImageToScrollView(image_URL: (self.jsonData?.HD_WALLPAPER![indexPath.row].wallpaper_image)!)
}
```

And I have following code portion in my scroll view controller:

```
import UIKit
import SDWebImage
class MyScrollViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myScrollView: UIScrollView!
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.myScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        self.myScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0
    }
    public func setImageToScrollView(image_URL: String){
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.myImageView!.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: image_URL), completed: {
                (image, error, cacheType, url) in
                //Completion Block ... Do Nothing
            })
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning(){
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView?{
        return self.myImageView
    }
}
```

I am using **SDWebImage**... an open source library to manage image caching.

**PROBLEM**: Sometimes image is loaded successfully without any error but most of the time my app **crashes** while executing **sd_setImage** api of **SDWebImage** framework with following error...... 
[image]

***Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value***

**QUERY**:

1. Firstly I called pushViewController and then I called my custom defined function. Is it proper way to call functions from collection view cell?
2. Why it shows unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.. though I get error free image url.

Comment: it seems that `self.myImageView` is `nil`

Comment: @RajibTheKing Please do if let binding for imageView instead of forcefully unwrapping it. your imageView getting nil sometime because of that your app get crashed

Answer (score 0):

Going back to your question:

> Firstly I called pushViewController and then I called my custom defined function. Is it proper way to call functions from collection view cell?

The answer to this is that you should NOT call functions that reference outlets until viewDidLoad.  The outlets are implicitly unwrapped optionals but aren't guaranteed to be there until viewDidLoad.  So, you have a race condition. Sometimes it works.

Change it so that you pass in a URL but don't call the function:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let VC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myScrollVC") as? MyScrollViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC!, animated: true)
    VC.imgURL =  self.jsonData?.HD_WALLPAPER![indexPath.row].wallpaper_image)!
}
```

Where imgURL is an instance variable on MyScrollViewContainer.  Then call your function from viewDidLoad, passing in imgURL.

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.myScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    self.myScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0
    setImageToScrollView(image_URL: imgURL)
}
```

That will change the timing of your calls -- ensuring that the outlet actually exists when the function is called.

=== the rest is my earlier answer (still relevant, but didn't solve your problem) ===

You don't need to wrap the SetImage call in a Dispatch.async. Your function should be one line:

```
public func setImageToScrollView(image_URL: String){
   self.myImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: image_URL))
}
```

That should make your problems go away. SetImage does its own dispatching and only updates the UI if the outlet still exists.

The other commenters pointed out why your code sometimes crashes (self.myImageView could be nil when your async block finishes) and how to protect against (if let binding or guard to check that the UIImageView outlet is still there).  Those are relevant techniques in general -- but SetImage takes care of all of that for you.

Comment: Initially my function was exactly same as you written. But it was frequently crashing. After adding DispatchQueue.main.async block, crash rate reduced. But still it was not solved.. Thank you for your effort. @ozzieozumo